# Последовательный вызов функций JS Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть JS код возвращающий `Promise`

```
  function SignCreate(certSubjectName, dataToSign, id) {
    //dataToSign = $("#DataToSignTxtBox").val();
    certSubjectName = $("#cert_info #subject b").text().replace("CN=", "");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        cadesplugin.async_spawn(function* (args) {
            try {
                if (certSubjectName === "") {
                    alert("Не выбран сертификат");
                    return;
                }
                var oStore = yield cadesplugin.CreateObjectAsync("CAdESCOM.Store");
                yield oStore.Open(CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE, CAPICOM_MY_STORE,
                    CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED);
                var CertificatesObj = yield oStore.Certificates;
                var oCertificates = yield CertificatesObj.Find(
                    CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_SUBJECT_NAME, certSubjectName);

                var Count = yield oCertificates.Count;
                if (Count == 0) {
                    throw ("Certificate not found: " + args[0]);
                }
                var oCertificate = yield oCertificates.Item(1);
                var oSigner = yield cadesplugin.CreateObjectAsync("CAdESCOM.CPSigner");
                yield oSigner.propset_Certificate(oCertificate);

                var oSignedData = yield cadesplugin.CreateObjectAsync("CAdESCOM.CadesSignedData");
                yield oSignedData.propset_ContentEncoding(cadesplugin.CADESCOM_BASE64_TO_BINARY);
                yield oSignedData.propset_Content(dataToSign);

                var sSignedMessage = yield oSignedData.SignCades(oSigner, CADESCOM_CADES_BES, true);

                yield oStore.Close();

                args[2](sSignedMessage);
                Verify(sSignedMessage, dataToSign);
                $("#SignatureTxtBox").html(sSignedMessage);

                SendSigninData(sSignedMessage, id);

            }
            catch (e) {
                args[3]("Failed to create signature. Error: " + cadesplugin.getLastError(err));
            }
        }, certSubjectName, dataToSign, resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

Есть функция внутри которой вызывается этот `SignCreate`

```
$("#SignMcBtn").click(function () {
        
        var checkeds = $(".checkedMC:checked");
        for (var n = 0; n < checkeds.length; n++) {
            var id = $(checkeds[n]).data("rbd");
            $.ajax({
                url: "SignCard",
                async: false,
                method: 'POST',
                data: { Id: id },
                success: function (html) {
                    if (id.length > 10 && html.length > 100) {
                        SignCreate(null, html, id);
                        if (checkSignStatusForCert(id)) {
                            $(checkeds[n]).parent().parent().hide();
                            $(checkeds[n]).prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Мне необходимо сделать вызов `checkSignStatusForCert(id)` но только после окончания работы функции `SignCreate(null, html, id);`

При этом редактировать `SignCreate` нельзя

Как в данном случае решить проблему чтобы вызов `checkSignStatusForCert(id)` шел только после отработки `SignCreate`  ?

Comment: SignCreate(null, html, id).then( ...)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 2):

```js
function a() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('a');

      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
}

function b() {
  console.log('b');
}

a().then(() => b());
```

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про [промисы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/thenhttps://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/thenhttps://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/thenhttps://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/thenhttps://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/thenhttps://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/thenhttps://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/thenhttps://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/thenhttps://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Это будет так

```
$("#SignMcBtn").click(function () {
        var checkeds = $(".checkedMC:checked");
        for (var n = 0; n < checkeds.length; n++) {
            var id = $(checkeds[n]).data("rbd");
            $.ajax({
                url: "SignCard",
                async: false,
                method: 'POST',
                data: { Id: id },
                success: function (html) {
                    if (id.length > 10 && html.length > 100) {
                        SignCreate(null, html, id).then( res => {
                         if (checkSignStatusForCert(id)) {
                            $(checkeds[n]).parent().parent().hide();
                            $(checkeds[n]).prop('checked', false);
                         }
                        }
                      )   
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Единственно не понятно этот участок

```
//тут что-то делаем
}, certSubjectName, dataToSign, resolve, reject);
```

Что это за участок и почему вы передаёте туда resolve, reject?

Comment: К сожалению все равно `checkSignStatusForCert` вызывается первой

Comment: @PolyakovSergey странно конечно

Comment: Это сторонняя библа CryptoPro сейчас выложу ее полный код

Comment: Увы там у вас если эта библа вызовет resolve то промис закончится даже при незаконченном вашем SignCreate